# How can I make a UV like this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, image

Look, I have this model:

[image]

And I'm just trying to make a UV like this (the landscapes):

[image]

[image]

I already have the two textures, which are these:

[image]

[image]

The mesh is just too complex for making a UV, I tried but finally gave up, isn't there an easy form to do this? It needs to be, these games are really old.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the simplest way to do it is would be to use Unwrap - Reset with your mesh simplified to a single quad per UV tile and then add more model detail after, you should keep in mind those devs worked with pretty low poly models so they probably used something pretty similar.

I don't think there's any easier way than this possible in Blender, other than standard unwrap/projecting & manually alligning things. It would be pretty sweet if there was a way to stretch the UV selection to fit the border of the tile though, in that case you could just split your mesh UVs into islands for each texture tile.

*This might be of relevance to you:* https://blenderartists.org/t/project-uv-coordinates-from-low-poly-mesh/629378/5

Comment: thank you so much for your answer!, I will keep in mind everything you told me :)